# ASN.1 encoded file

Tags: c, asn.1

I need to create an ASN.1 BER encoded file with multiple records. I've been searching for one (tools like oss, asn1c, ... etc), but I can't find one that suits me with a full example on how multiple records can be encoded in one file.

Does anyone know a good tool?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tools won't really help you design your file-format, or *protocol*; that is a manual task that you must perform.  You will need to design the rules of how data is stored and in what form each element will take.

The tools will help with implementation, allowing you to take your protocol definition and generating C or C++ code that is capable of decoding and encoding files that conform to that protocol.

The company I work for uses [OSS Nokalva](http://www.oss.com/), which is the best, but expensive.  I have also used [asn1c](http://lionet.info/asn1c), for personal projects, with success.

Comment: I have the .asn definitions , but how do I add multiple record using asn1c ? can you give me some tips or implementation because their documentation is short on examples. Thanks

Comment: and also how expensive is oss nokalva ?

Comment: @pufos There is nothing special about multiple records - your PDU's can be structured sequentially and the decoder will take them off one-at-a-time.  It costs thousands of pounds per year for support.

Comment: OSS offers a variety of licensing and pricing models (http://www.oss.com/products/purchase.html) to match many different needs.   OSS ASN.1 commercial products are a cost effective solution for even the most cost budget constrained projects.

Comment: @PaulThorpe Are you possibly associated with OSS in some way?

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes, I am one of the ASN.1 experts at OSS Nokalva.

Answer (score 1):

You can use asn1c and define multiple records with

MultipleRecords :: SEQUENCE OF SingleRecord